# Manipulating Jenkins build parameter with groovy script, used for sonar analysis

Tags: groovy, mercurial, jenkins, sonarqube, atlassian-sourcetree

At the moment, i have Sourcetree making my branches, they will be called "feature/my-branch" and i can send that to my hg repo, and retrieve it from jenkins and build.

but, sonar does not accept "/" in the branch name, so i wanted to change "/" to "-" or something.. in a groovy script in the build phase.

Is something like that possible?

my solution so far:

```
parameter: BRANCH
default value: feature/my-branch
groovy scrips: def replaced = BRANCH.replaceAll(/\//, '-')
```

but it will not recognize my BRANCH, i've tried adding it in all sorts of ways..

any help to make my `"feature/my-branch"` be analyzed by sonar will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How are you invoking SonarQube on Jenkins? I assume it's via the SonarQube Jenkins Plugin. You could use the [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) to edit `BRANCH`. Here's an untested possibility for you to mull over:

`SONAR_BRANCH=${BRANCH//\//-}`

And in the SonarQube plugin's "Additional options":

`sonar.branch=${env.SONAR_BRANCH}`

If that won't work, or if you don't want EnvInject, you could do everything in one *Execute Shell* build step:

```
SONAR_BRANCH=${BRANCH//\//-}
mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.branch=${SONAR_BRANCH}
```